# raspistill timelapse stops producing output

Tags: camera, raspbian-stretch, raspicam, pi-zero-w, picamera

So I'm trying to run a timelapse for 24-36 (or until storage space is full) but raspistill seems to stop producing output after anywhere from 50-300 stills.

```
raspistill -t 129600000 -tl 5000 -o tlapse%016d.jpg -ex auto -awb auto --quality 100 --nopreview --thumb none --burst
```

Raspistill doesn't give any sort of error code and appears to be running from the terminal.  I did have an issue with it stalling on missing frames but it doesn't seem to do that.

Any information as to how to keep it running and producing output would be very much appreciated.

For information:

- Raspi Zero W
- Raspbian Stretch
- Raspi Camera Module V2
- 128gb USB stick for storage formatted as vFAT and automounts at boot

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Raspberry Pi 3 B+, Raspbian Stretch 9, camera module v1.3, saving to SD. Using following flags, should be 12 pictures over 1 hour.

```
raspistill -v -bm -vf -hf -awb cloud -br 60 -sa 40 -t 3600000 -tl 300000 -q 100 -o image%04d.jpg
```

I was getting the issue where mmal skips frames and names an image randomly (or by time stamp?) and then quits the process. but I added -bm now and it just seems to stop capturing images after several are taken but the process does not fail.

EDIT: I'm now running timelapses with Python, the picamera module and it's working fine, no skipped frames or inexplicable stopped output. [Here's](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html) the resource I'm using. After several tests with raspistill I concluded that it quit around 20 minutes no matter what time lapse interval was set.