# raspistill quality issues: single photos vs timelapse

Tags: raspbian-stretch, raspicam, pi-zero-w

For some reason there seems to be a huge jump in quality when using the -tl switch for a timelapse over individual pictures.

```
raspistill -t 1 -o /mnt/usb128/photos/test%016d.jpg -ex auto -awb auto --quality 100 --nopreview --thumb none --restart
```

vs

```
raspistill -t 129600000 -tl 5000 -o /mnt/usb128/photos/tlapse%016d.jpg -ex auto -awb auto --quality 100 --nopreview --thumb none --restart
```

The stills taken manually without the -tl switch are dull and washed out colour and have file sizes of approx 1.7mb.  Conversely, the timelapse photos ramp up in quality and the files jump to 4mb per image.

I'm trying to get a *long* timelapse so either need the quality of the individual stills to be higher so i can run it via script or cron, or the timelapse to be more reliable (previous post on this:  [raspistill timelapse stops producing output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94461/raspistill-timelapse-stops-producing-output) )

Any info would be much appreciated.

Cheers